# jQuery each loop stopping after first instance of class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have written some code to distribute images evenly in a horizontal div while keeping their heights uniform, and it seems to work well, except for the fact that it resizes the first instance of the class horizontal and then stops. If I manually run the code again in the chrome inspector console it resizes the next one, but not on page load.

JS is as follows:

```
$('.horizontal').each(function( i, div ){

  var heights = [];
  var sum = 0;
  var count = 0;

  $(div).find('img').each(function( j, img){
    heights.push($(img).get(0).naturalWidth / $(img).get(0).naturalHeight);
  });

  $.each(heights,function(){sum+=parseFloat(this) || 0;});

  $(div).find('img').each(function( k, img){
    $(img).css( 'width', heights[count] * ( 100 / sum ) + "%");
    count += 1;
  });

});
```

Here is a JSFiddle based on what was kindly provided by lshettyl with my code (ignore the weird html brackets, they are just to fix a whitespace issue)
http://jsfiddle.net/rck79c1L/1/

Ok so this works, and as noted in the comment the issue is not with each not looping, rather misreporting of the naturalwidth/height of the images.

And seems to have been fixed by changing

```
$(document).ready(function()
```

to

```
$(window).load(function()
```

Comment: `$.each(heights,function(index,val){sum+=parseFloat(val) || 0;});` ?

Comment: why heights[k-1] and not heights[k] in your last each?

Comment: Check each collection you're looping over: `console.log($('.horizontal').length)`, `console.log($(div).find('img').length)`, `console.log(heights.length)` and `console.log($(div).find('img'))` - Are they all what you expect?

Comment: @TusharGupta - Is `this` and `val` not the same in a jQuery each?

Comment: `each` function has two parameters 1. index (of the element)2. object (the element reference)

Comment: Very messy code with unnecessary `$.each`. At the max, you may need 2 `$.each`. Put your code in a fiddle, create a working example, and one of us would help fix it.

Comment: The k-1 was a mistake that I forgot to change before pasting. Fixed up now with a bad albeit working method.

Comment: The lengths are all what I would expect.

Comment: Ok so upon some more investigation it turns out the problem is not that it doesn't loop, its that sometimes the naturalWidth/naturalHeight is reported as being 0, leading to a NaN when trying to get the ratio.  So being new to stackoverflow, should I make a new question to find out why this is happening or can it be answered here?

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in comments, `$.each(heights,function(){sum+=parseFloat(this) || 0;});` has an error and also this `each` is redundant as the sum could be done in your 2nd `each` itself.

You don't need to convert an image object to a jQuery object and then back to image object to get it's property. It's just pointless round trips => `$(img).get(0).naturalWidth`

`$('.horizontal').each` => You don't need an `each` here as you could simply do `$('.horizontal img')`

Here is your code, simplified with reduced `each` loops.

```
var heights = [];
var sum = 0;
var $images = $('.horizontal img');

$images.each(function( i, img ){

    var height = img.naturalWidth / img.naturalHeight || 0;
    sum += parseFloat(height);
    heights.push(height);
});

$images.each(function( k, img ) {
    $(img).css({
        'width': (heights[k] * ( 100 / sum )).toFixed(2) + "%"
    });
});
```

Here is [a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dy3bvodd/) for the above.

Comment: Still new at this, most of that code was cobbled together from various examples across the web. Yours looks a lot better and applies to all instances of the class, but is not resizing images properly. In your example there is two identically sized images, so the widths should be set at 50%, but they are both set to 16.67%. Its probably a math error that I should be able to spot, once I get my head around the changes.

Comment: This code ends up assigning the widths as though all of the images in the page are on the same line. Whereas it is supposed to be only the images in each div on the same line.

Comment: Not very clear, set up an example in a fiddle as that would help us debug in real-time. Sure, in that case, you need to each thru the divs and also correct the math to suit your needs.

Comment: In the JSFiddle, there are 6 images in total. So the code is giving each image a width of 16.67% (1/6). Should be 3 lots of each image being 50% as there are 2 on each line.

Comment: So, your formula is number of images / 100%?

Answer (score 0):

So aside from the messy code, the problem turned out to be naturalHeight / naturalWidth sometimes being reported as 0 (sometimes correctly). This led to a divide by zero in the code, and therefore nothing happening.

Changing the start to:

```
$(window).load(function(){...
```

seems to have fixed the issue.